# Quanto tempo leva um incremento do tipo x++?

Tags: java, desempenho, operadores

Quanto tempo em média um incremento do tipo i++ leva para ser feito.

---

Tendo em vista as respostas e comentários colocados aqui: Eu fiz esta pergunta porque estou com um método para enviar e-mails quando certa condição é alcançada.

Eu não posso usar algo do tipo `Thread.Sleep()` para não ficar havendo reenvio constante. Partindo do princípio de que não tenho como mudar aquela condição de forma programática devido a possibilidade dela ser física (como um sensor estar quebrado ou algo do gênero), pensei em testar um contador para "simular o tempo". Pelo menos, foi a primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça.

Comment: Acho que você poderia fazer um benchmark, pois os resultado são muito variantes pra cada máquina, no caso do `++` e `--` é provável que seja impercepitivel, mesmo usando milionésimo de segundos pra calcular.

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta, se tiver um motivo específico para a pergunta, complemente, que eu complemento a resposta.

Comment: HDeiro, sugiro que crie uma outra resposta expondo seu problema verdadeiro, incluindo algum trecho de código relevante. Existem vários mecanismos em Java para lidar com eventos e temporização e não dá pra saber qual o mais adequado apenas por essas informações. Abraço!

Comment: Pesquise sobre `Scheduler`, provavelmente é o que você precisa. Agendar rotinas de tarefas, ou simplesmente, loops de envio.

Comment: A aplicação está em meu estágio. Segunda-feira adiciono!

Comment: @HDeiro Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma, usando Joda-time. :)

Answer (score 10):

Muito pouco. São alguns poucos ciclos de processador (ele em si pode ser 1, depende do processador). É até difícil medir. Medir coisas assim são complicadas porque o tempo gasto para fazer o código executar e fazer a medição será bem superior ao do trabalho executado.

De qualquer forma é irrelevante saber, esta é uma das operações mais rápidas que existe no processador. E se você precisa dela, terá que usar.

O que torna lento alguma coisa no código não é isto. Não se preocupe com esse tipo de detalhe, ainda mais usando Java.

Após a edição da pergunta fica claro que isto não faz sentido mesmo, e aqui fica como curiosidade. Você não pode usar um dos operadores mais rápidos para gastar tempo. Mesmo que ele fosse lento só traria problemas para a aplicação. O problema é outro e a solução não passa pelo que foi perguntado. Vale a pena abrir outra pergunta explicando o real problema que está enfrentando para que as pessoas possam te ajudar e te dar uma solução adequada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Não faz muito sentido falar no tempo que uma instrução específica leva para executar, fora do contexto do programa como um todo, devido ao [***pipeline***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(hardware)) do processador. Nem toda instrução (sobretudo no Java) leva o mesmo tempo para executar, algumas podem levar um ciclo [amortizado] e outras podem levar vários ciclos. Se seu incremento ocorre logo depois de uma operação que leva vários ciclos - e essas duas operações são independentes uma da outra - então o tempo que essa instrução vai levar é efetivamente zero (i.e. o programa vai levar o mesmo tempo com ou sem essa instrução). Pois o processador vai "encaixar" o incremento no "tempo de espera" da instrução anterior.

No mais, uma operação de incremento é algo muito simples, que não deve levar mais que o mínimo necessário pro processador executar uma instrução "atômica" (de novo, amortizado pode chegar a um único ciclo), assumindo é claro que a variável esteja num registrador. O que é razoável de se supor, ainda que o acesso a um valor qualquer (digamos, um elemento de um array) possa sofrer vários *cache misses* (ou mesmo provocar uma paginação) *o incremento em si* vai levar muito pouco tempo.